# Hibernate ManyToOne with two columns

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

Basically I want to refer the start city and end city to Bay object. Which is already created.

Table got crated .....But I can find only one bay field. And while saving

19:14:52,723 DEBUG [SqlExceptionHelper] could not execute statement [n/a]
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "bay" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (3, 0, null, null, null, null).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:420)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:366)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:186)

Generated Table :

CREATE TABLE iot.vehicle
(
  vehicle_id integer NOT NULL,
  cost bigint,
  endtime timestamp without time zone,
  satrttime timestamp without time zone,
  vehicletype integer,
  bay integer NOT NULL,`enter code here`
  CONSTRAINT vehicle_pkey PRIMARY KEY (vehicle_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_1w93t3827hqk1dji0s585ocf1 FOREIGN KEY (bay)
      REFERENCES iot.bay (bay_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
}

public class Vehicle {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "VEHICLE_ID")
private int vehicleId;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="BAY", nullable = false,  insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Bay startCity;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="BAY", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Bay endCity;

@Column(name = "SATRTTIME")
private Date startTime;

@Column(name = "ENDTIME")
private Date endTime;

@Column(name = "COST")
private long cost;

@Column(name = "VEHICLETYPE")
private TranportType vehicleType;
```

}

public class Bay {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "BAY_ID")
private int bayId;

@Column(name = "COUNTRY", nullable = false)
String country;

@Column(name = "CITINAME", nullable = false)
String citiName;


@Column(name = "BAYTYPE")
TranportType bayType;
```

//getters/setters
}

Comment: When you save Vehicle, you obviously don't set the bay value (startCity and endCity). And don't give them the same name (@JoinColumn(name="...") <- name attribute)

Comment: Perfect......It is my mistake gave the same value.....I gave diffrent values and working it now.

Comment: so I wrote an answer so it's better seen by other people. You can accept it since it works for you just to make it obvious.

Answer (score 1):

When you persist Vehicle, you obviously don't set the bay value (`startCity` and `endCity`).

And don't give them the same name:

```
@JoinColumn(name="...") //<- change name attribute here
```